# windows WPF and XAML button changing

Tags: wpf, xaml, button

I am trying to make a play/pause `Button`.
When the `Play Button` is clicked, it will bind to the `StartStopWatch` command.
The `Play Button` will then change to a `Pause Button` which will bind to the `PauseStopWatch` command.
My problem is. I don't know how to keep the style it has and change them interchangablly. Currently I have two different buttons, but I want to merge them together and put them as one.
My buttons are as follows. I want to have it on `MouseClick`, it changes also! Thanks!

```
<Button x:Name="StartButton" Style="{DynamicResource StartTimerButton}"
        Width="24" Height="24" Margin="5,0,5,0" ToolTip="Start Timer"
        Command="{Binding StartStopWatch}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>

<Button x:Name="StopButton" Style="{DynamicResource StopTimerButton}"
        Width="20" Height="20" Margin="0,0,5,0" ToolTip="Stop Timer"
        Command="{Binding StopStopWatch}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

Does anyone have any Suggestions?

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve. Do you want to dynamically switch the style and tooltip (which can be made a part of style BTW) on your button?

Comment: When the button is CLicked, then It changes.

Example.

You have a Play button.
When you click the play button it changes to a pause button.
WHen you click the pause button it changes to a play button.
But when its on play, it binds to the command play.
WHen its on pause it binds to the command pause.
ALso, i'm trying to keep my same styles on my buttons. i have a red and green button. Red = stop and green = go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way is to use a ToggleButton and utilize its Checked and UnChecked state. You can change the ControlTemplate Theme based on that 
For the Command, why cant you create a Single Command for StopWatch and pass true/false as CommandParameter to distinguish the execution

```
<ToggleButton Name="yourToggleButton"
    Command="{Binding StartStopCommand}"
    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName= yourToggleButton, Path=IsChecked}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a button that can be in two states, consider using `ToggleButton`, and bind all you want to its `IsChecked` property. In particular, you can bind the button's `Style` depending on `IsChecked` wholesale (using a converter), or you can just use triggers inside your style to change appearance (including tooltip) depending on the value of `IsChecked`.